# Javascript string interpolation gives different result than string concatenation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, concatenation, interpolation

I ran across a case where Javascript string interpolation is not giving the same result as string concatenation.

Here is a simplified version of the code showing the difference:

```
const mmt = moment();
console.log('concatenated: ' + mmt); // "concatenated: 1651070909974"
console.log(`interpolated: ${mmt}`); // "interpolated: Wed Apr 27 2022 10:48:29 GMT-0400"
console.log('mmt.valueOf(): ' + mmt.valueOf()); // "mmt.valueOf(): 1651070909974"
console.log('mmt.toString(): ' + mmt.toString()); // "mmt.toString(): Wed Apr 27 2022 10:48:29 GMT-0400"
```

So my immediate thought was that it was due to a difference in `.toString()` and `.valueOf()`, so I made a small test object to verify:

```
const obj = {
  toString: () => 'toString',
  valueOf: () => 'valueOf',
};

console.log('concatenated: ' + obj); // "concatenated: valueOf"
console.log(`interpolated: ${obj}`); // "interpolated: toString"
console.log('obj.valueOf(): ' + obj.valueOf()); // "obj.valueOf(): valueOf"
console.log('obj.toString(): ' + obj.toString()); // "obj.toString(): toString"
```

However, when I tried this with a Date object (which also has a different result from `.toString()` vs `.valueOf()`), I do *not* get the same behavior--this time interpolation and concatenation both use the `.toString()` value:

```
const dte = new Date();
console.log('concatenated: ' + dte); // "concatenated: Wed Apr 27 2022 10:48:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
console.log(`interpolated: ${dte}`); // "interpolated: Wed Apr 27 2022 10:48:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
console.log('dte.valueOf(): ' + dte.valueOf()); // "dte.valueOf(): 1651070909974"
console.log('dte.toString(): ' + dte.toString()); // "dte.toString(): Wed Apr 27 2022 10:48:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```

**So my questions is:** What are the actual rules for how an interpolated value is converted to a string when concatenated vs interpolated, and why does Date seem to be different from other objects? (I have tried to look this up, but thus far my googling has been unsuccessful...)

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yep1rocq/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in behaviour is really related to the `+` operator, which has a specific procedure behind it:

The ECMAScript specification on the abstract operation [ToPrimitive](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-toprimitive) specifies that if no type hint is provided (as is the case with [the `+` operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator)) the following happens:

- If the object has a `Symbol.toPrimitive` method, then it will be called (with hint "default"). This method may forward the call to `toString`. This is the case with `Date` objects.
- If the object has no such method, "number" is the default and `valueOf` will be called. This is the case with the `moment` object.

The reason for this complex procedure in handling the `+` operator, is that it also serves for the arithmetic addition.

This complexity is not present in evaluating template literals, where always *string concatenation* is intended, and so the `Symbol.toPrimitive` method will be called with the "string" hint (instead of "default"), or if that method does not exist, `toString` will be called.

So your assumption that `+` is a pure string concatenation, is not that accurate. See how it is also different when you use the `.concat` method:

```js
const mmt = moment();
console.log('concatenated: '.concat(mmt));
// Not same result as with +
console.log('plus operator: ' + mmt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you! i have never heard of `.toPrimitive` before, so none of my googling found it

Comment: @Kip It's `[Symbol.toPrimitive]`, not `.toPrimitive`